# Django profile model

Tags: django

I am beginner on django and trying to create a profile model that interrelate "User" built-in model via One-To-One relation field, it results impossible to span the user model properties by profile model instance and vise versa.
Can someone help me.

models.py

```
from django.db import models     
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

 class Profile(models.Model):
     users=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     image=models.ImageField(default='profilepic.jpg',upload_to='profile_pictures')
     location=models.CharField(max_length=100)

   def __str__(self):
     return self.users.username
```

profileTemplate.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Profile</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <h2>{{user.username}}</h2>
    <img src='{{user.Profile.image}}'> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this `<img src='{{ user.profile.image.url }}'> `

Comment: thank you very much 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a lowercase profile as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield)

```
<img src='{{user.profile.image}}'>
```

Comment: thank you very much 